# c++ enum class not displayed correctly

Tags: c++, enums

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


enum Suit : long {Heart, Club, Spade, Diamond};
enum class Color : char {Red = '*', Blue, Yellow, Green};
int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    auto suit = Suit::Club; 
    auto color = Color::Yellow;
    cout << setw(37) << left << "Suit value: " << setw(5) << right << suit << endl;
    cout << setw(37) << left << "Suit value +10: " << setw(5) << right << suit + 10 << endl;
    cout << setw(37) << left << "Color value: " << setw(5) << right << static_cast< char >(color) << endl;
    cout << setw(37) << left << "Color value +10: " << setw(5) << right << static_cast< int >(color) << endl;

    wchar_t x;
    wcin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Result running in vs2017:

```
Suit value:                              1
Suit value +10:                         11
Color value:                             ,
Color value +10:                        44
```

So the char `*` was printed as a comma, why?

Comment: No, Red would have displayed `*`, Yellow displays `,` because the ascii table is `*+,-`

Comment: Ah, my bad. Need a coffee right now.

Answer (score 3):

`Red` is `'*'`, and `Yellow` is `'*' + 2`, which is `','`.

More specifically, 42 is the ASCII value for `'*'`, and 44 is for `','`, and `Red` and `Yellow` differ by 2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ascii Code Table]

As you know how `enum` work, variable of `enum` get value +1 from last value. for Ex-

```
enum {
      sunday = 0, monday, tueday, ... , saturday 
}
```

if you acces the value of `monday` it will `1`.
as you have given `red = '*'`. so for complier your `enum` will look like this.

```
enum {
      red = '*',
      blue = '+',
      yellow = ','
}
```

so now you know.